# Should/Can I post a question for which I already have an answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, self-answer, instant-self-answer

While answering a question about *Why something doesn't work*, I've come up with a workaround idea that is very unusual, and might be an innovating idea.

I encouraged the OP to post a new question, specific asking for a workaround, so I could provide my answer, but didn't get a response from him.

My question is: **Should/Can I post a question (that I'll answer myself), just to share the idea?**

Since it's not an issue I'm having, would it be correct?

Alternatively, I could post my solution to the question that originated the idea, but I believe it would not be reachable to someone who is looking for it, since the question title is deceiving...

Comment: How is it any different to ask for a workaround to solve a problem than for a "good" solution to the problem?  In either case the question is the same, "How do I do X?"  One could answer with either a workaround or a more comprehensive solution.  Creating a new question would just be making a duplicate.

Comment: I'm sorry if it's a bit confuse. I mean to ask a question (that I'm going to answer myself) with the intent to share an idea...

Comment: @LcSalazar That's the entire point behind "Self-Answer" questions. Just make sure the question is up to quality standards even without the answer, and ensure the answer is also up to quality standards. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone... The answer to my question is in the duplicate flag pointed by @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå - That should be marked as the duplicate